# Unable to apply autoformat on precommit hook

Tags: java, spring, git, maven, pre-commit-hook

I'm building a Pre-commit [Git Hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) script to apply code formatting with the help of [Spring JavaFormat](https://github.com/spring-io/spring-javaformat?tab=readme-ov-file#spring-java-format) :

```bash
#!/bin/sh

./mvnw spring-javaformat:apply
```

When I commit an unformatted file, I notice the following:

- The command passes (after I verify my Git console).
- The target file is committed successfully without formatting changes.
- The formatting changes are applied but **not committed**.

I tried many ways to make it happen, but not one works, I'm wondering why and what is the way out for this?

This is how I added the plugin to my pom.xml file:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.spring.javaformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-javaformat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.40</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <goals>
                <goal>apply</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

#### System Requirements

- Maven v3.9.5 (with wrapper)
- Spring Boot v3.2
- Spring JavaFormat v0.0.40

Comment: The gist of the duplicate is that you need to `git add` the modifications made by the formatter.

Comment: I don't get it sorry. Do you mean i should write `git add` into the script file ?

Comment: You'll need to add the changes made by the auto-format to the current commit with `git add <filename>` or `git add .`, so yes, you need to do that in your script file.